# Django - How do I download data once a day using Pandas for my site?

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner to Django and am currently building a site that displays stock prices. To do that, I need to download (or update) the stock prices once a day. I know that I can retrieve stock prices using Pandas. However, I would like my site to do it once everyday at a specific time, instead of retrieving data every time a visitor visits the view. I'm a bit stuck here and did a lot of Google searches. Can someone please point me to a link that I can read up on?

EDIT: I'm currently making this site on my own computer so I haven't uploaded my files yet.

Comment: What platform are you on? There is most likely a way of scheduling a cronjob or scheduled event that can serve your purpose.

Comment: @JamieBull On my local server/computer.

Comment: Which is Windows, Linux, Mac?

Comment: @JamieBull It's on a Mac

Comment: Then the answer below about Linux also applies. Have a look at [this article](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_cron_jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Linux box (like Debian[0]), and have cron[1] up and running:

1. Create a Shell Script to call a program you will write to get the data using Pandas.
2. Use `crontab -l` to edit your crontab file and add you script to execute at any time you need.

   - [0] https://www.debian.org/
   - [1] http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab